# How do I Set the State of NGRX Store in StoryBook & Angular tests?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, storybook

Does anyone know how or have links for using StoryBook & Angular with NGRX Store ?

I have followed the StoryBook tutorial but still cannot figure out how to use StoryBook with NGRX Store.
I can use StoryBook with Angular Dumb Components fine.
I need to be able to set the NGRX Store State for the stories of my Nested components.

eg.
In my **SmartComponent** I have:

`this.accountDebtor$ = this.coreStore.select( coreSelector.selectAccountDebtorState );`

In the **Story** I have:

```
export const LoadedAccountPanel = (args) => ({
 component: AccountComponent,
 props: args,
});
LoadedAccountPanel.args = {
 panelData: {},
 accountDebtor$: <-- How do I set the State so this gets set using the store ???,
};
```

Comment: We are using the provideMockStore (https://ngrx.io/api/store/testing/provideMockStore) to inject our data. It works for our Angular Testing Library tests and our Storybook.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Đorđe Petrović commented, you can use provideMockStore to achieve this.

**Here's an example:**

```
import { provideMockStore } from '@ngrx/store/testing';


// your desired data
const example_data = {
  foo: bar,
};

// the state for the mockStore
const initialState = {
  state_key: example_data
};


export default {
  title: 'YourComponent',
  component: YourComponent,
  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
      providers: [
        provideMockStore({ initialState })
      ]
    })
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jerry
 This is a working solution and I am now using it.  What I have discovered is that it does not update the real store. I need a solution that will update the store so that parent / child components in the story can use the updated data.  Is this even possible??   eg.  a parent component selects a userAccount, saves it in the Store so the child components that are subscribed to the selected store slice can react to the changes.